# hide / show multiple div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to hide / show some `div` box, by clicking one text line. To summarize, it must do something like Android File Explorer.

[image]

[image]

These 2 pictures show the difference when I click on the `Mes Vidéos` text field.

Here is a part of my current code :

```js
    function folderChange(param) {
      var video=document.getElementById('v');
      var file=document.getElementById('f');
      if(param==1) {
        video.style.display = "block";
        file.style.display = "none";
      }
      else {
        file.style.display = "block";
        video.style.display = "none";
      }  
    }
```

```css
    .filefolder {
      display: none;
    }
    .videofolder {
      display: block;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="groove2"></div>
      <div class="chemin filefolder" id="f" style="background-color:#FAF9F8" style="color:#BDBCBA"><font color="#575654">Flashdisk <b>> Mes Fichiers</b></font></div>
      <div class="chemin videofolder" id="v" style="background-color:#FAF9F8" style="color:#BDBCBA"><font color="#575654">Flashdisk ><b onclick="folderChange(0)"> Mes Fichiers</b> ><b> Mes Vidéos</b></font></div>
      <div class="groove2"></div>
      <div id="madiv">
        <div class="videofolder" id="v">
          <div>
             <input type="checkbox" id="contactChoice1" name="fichier" value="Video1">
             <img class="icone" src="video.jpg">
             <label for="Video1">Video1.mp4</label>
          </div>
          <div class="groove"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="f" class="filefolder">
          <div class="folder">
             <img class="icone" src="dossier.jpg" onclick="folderChange(1)">
             <p onclick="folderChange(1)"><b>Mes Vidéos</b></p>
          </div>
          <div class="groove"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="filefolder">
          <div id="f" class="blok">
             <input class="off" type="checkbox" disabled="true" id="contactChoice1" name="fichieroff" value="Video1">
             <img class="icone" src="xls.jpg">
             <label for="Video1"><b>Resultats.xlsx</b></label>
          </div>
          <div class="groove"></div>
        </div>
```

What I'm expected to do is to change the `display` value of `videofolder` and `filefolder` when I click on `Mes Vidéos`, but on the screen, nothing change (or just the path display).

I'm pretty newbie on HTML and Javascript.

NB : there is no file reader currently, I'm just working on the display.

Comment: You use the ids `v` and `f` multiple times. But ids should be unique and only have one element. You can use the class list to select multiple elements with one selector.

Comment: Adding to @Adder 's comment, you can also use a for loop to cycle through the elements and change the properties there.

Comment: @JoelTrauger Which parameter could I use on the `for`loop (the *exit* parameter)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have two types of things to show/hide, you can iterate through them with a single line, and apply `classList.toggle()` to them:

```js
function folderChange() {
  document.querySelectorAll(".video, .file").forEach(el => el.classList.toggle("show"))
}
```

```css
.video,
.file {
  display: none
}

.show {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<button onclick="folderChange()">Show Files</button>
<button onclick="folderChange()">Show Videos</button>

<p class="video">video a</p>
<p class="file show">file a</p>
<p class="video">video b</p>
<p class="video">video c</p>
<p class="file show">file b</p>
<p class="file show">file c</p>
<p class="file show">file d</p>
<p class="video">video d</p>
<p class="video">video e</p>
<p class="file show">file e</p>
```